# i have a complex json i want to push in cassandra.how should I design my table in Cassandra?

Tags: json, cassandra, nested

I have a complex JSON I want to push in Cassandra where I will have questions and options mapping.how should I design my table in Cassandra?what should be my table architecture?

```
insert into questions_options JSON'{
  "qid": "12736467",
  "chapter_id": "12",
  "subject_id": 19482065,
  "topic_id": 216.28,
  "type": "picked",
  "content": "on time",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "marks": 12,
  "hint": "do something",
  "explanations": "do something dude",
  "created_by": 1232,
  "create_on": "2013-06-10",
  "options": [
    {
      "option_id": 1,
      "option_text": "ACBD",
      "sort_order": 1,
      "correct_option": true
    },
    {
      "option_id": 2,
      "option_text": "bcdd",
      "sort_order": 2,
      "correct_option": true
    }
  ]
}'
```

I wrote the below create table query.Is it right?

```
create table questions_options (
    qid bigint,
    chapter_id bigint,
    subject_id int,
    topic_id int,
    class varchar,
    type varchar,
    content text,
    difficulty tinyint,
    marks int,
    hint text,
    explanations text,
    created_by bigint,
    create_on timestamp,
    option_id bigint,
    option_text text,
    sort_order int,
    correct_option boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY((qid), option_id) 
);
```

Comment: In Cassandra you have to design your table the way you want to query.

Comment: can u please give me the create table query? As in the above JSON it is one to many mapping and i want to put that in one table itself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cassandra you have to design your table the way you want to query, not by the one you want to insert.

By the way, you asked what will be the table that support your json.

Here is how you can convert :

- For each json key create a column in cassandra with the same name
- Define that field data type by the json field value.
- If the value is also a json object then create custom data type in cassandra
- Define primary key By analyzing your your read query.

For your json this will be the schema :

```
CREATE TYPE option (
    option_id bigint,
    option_text text,
    sort_order int,
    correct_option boolean
);

CREATE TABLE questions_options (
    qid bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    chapter_id bigint,
    class text,
    content text,
    create_on date,
    created_by bigint,
    difficulty int,
    explanations text,
    hint text,
    marks int,
    options list<frozen<option>>,
    subject_id int,
    topic_id double,
    type text
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ashraful Islam